# how to merge rows in gridview and add subheading in one column of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have to design an invoice like structure for that I have to show the hotel details, but the total  cost of the package and vehicle only

```
S.No.   Description                          Unit       Total in INR

        Accommodation Charges                              21,954.00
1.      1N – Nest Resort (22 Dec 2013)       01 Rooms
        1N – Hill View (23 Dec 2013)         01 Rooms
        1N – Kumily Gate (24 Dec 2013)       01 Rooms
        1N – Cosy Houseboat (25 Dec 2013)    01 Rooms

Service Tax 1.236 %                                         271.00

Total                                                      22,225.00
```

This I have to show in grid view, how to add heading accommodation charges and show the total value in front of that heading.

Comment: I think you should try `Repeater Control` instead of `Gridview` [How to use RepeaterControl](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: cn u plz tell me i never worked wid repeater how cn i show this design in repeater control...